# NeuroPH GPS Training Set

Tags: java, gps, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

i have a bunch of gps coordinates. and these coordinates come from a specific location which i know the exact gps coordinates.

```
8.228619|124.237528
8.228619|124.237528
8.228583|124.237560
8.228562|124.237586
8.228565|124.237595
8.228709|124.237649
8.228707|124.237650

this is the exact coordinate of that location:8.22832|124.23761
```

in neuroph i use multilayer perceptron and use 2 input and 2 output. and in the training data i use the coordinates from the data i gathered as the input and the output layer are the gps data of the exact coordinate. when i start training, it wont learn why? I just need to know how to input them into training data as input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, you *have* to run Neuroph as administrator (right-click on the executable/link and choose "Run as administrator") in order to train your neural network. If not, you will always see the

```
Starting neural network training...
Training network XXX using data set YYY
Training error: null
```

error message.

[image]

Comment: Running as administrator did not change anything for me.